# What are these weird characters and why do they act weird and break HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ascii, meta, non-ascii-characters

These characters were found in a recent ios vulnarability. The webpage contains the below characters.

Few characters:

> ţ̴̨̢̨̨̧̧̨̡̡̡̡̨̢̛̛̛̪͇͕̱̼̦̦̝̯̪̗̠̞̪̤̲̫͎̫͉͍̪̗̬̣̺͓̞̩͇͖̯
>   ţ̴̨̢̨̨̧̧̨̡̡̡̡̨̢̛̛̛̪͇͕̱̼̦̦̝̯̪̗̠̞̪̤̲̫͎̫͉͍̪̗̬̣̺͓̞̩͇͖̯
>   ţ̴̨̢̨̨̧̧̨̡̡̡̡̨̢̛̛̛̪͇͕̱̼̦̦̝̯̪̗̠̞̪̤̲̫͎̫͉͍̪̗̬̣̺͓̞̩͇͖̯
>   ţ̴̨̢̨̨̧̧̨̡̡̡̡̨̢̛̛̛̪͇͕̱̼̦̦̝̯̪̗̠̞̪̤̲̫͎̫͉͍̪̗̬̣̺͓̞̩͇͖̯

Edit:

subquestion: 
Can we restrict users from entering such characters?

Comment: Cool, I think...?

Comment: yeah but what are those ?  already a downvote :3

Comment: Not really sure

Comment: Would you please format the post better? Now half of your question is not even visible/readable due to overlap.

Comment: @MaximVolgin done.